# Highcharts Chart.container Issue IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I have a chart created through highchart on a webpage that can be clicked to navigate to different page on our website. This is handled using the click event provided by Highchart. This functionality works well in Chrome, FireFox, IE10. However, with IE8 this works randomly.  Finding it hard to understand the problem because of the randomness.

As an alternative solution, I wrapped highchart div within another div and added a link on that div. If I set chart.container.onclick = null as well, the link on div gets fired correctly without interfering with highcharts event. However randomly IE8 complains that chart.container is undefined, which I dont understand why.

When I use the 'Watch expression' on IE8 to check what is going on, I can see that many properties for the chart are not available when the chart link does not work (For instance container, chartBackground, hasRendered, legend etc.). All these and many more are available when the link work. I suspect something breaks, but cant figure out what.

Can someone please point out Why is it that sometimes there are so many properties available whereas sometimes so few? What are potential causes to investigate?

The main issue I think is understanding why IE8 randomly complains about chart.container property.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you create simple live example with that issue? Maybe you have old version for Highcharts? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/483/show/

Comment: Sorry, I had missed an important detail in my question. I have edited the question. My code looks somewhat like this http://jsfiddle.net/88QCw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing variable chart before it gets chart-object. Use callback function instead: http://jsfiddle.net/88QCw/2/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            click: function() {
               location.href ="http://www.bing.com";    
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
}, function (chart){    
    chart.container.onclick = null;
});
```